# The Longest Pesach

Tags: history, passover, historical-figures

There is a famous tape by [Rabbi Shmuel Kunda entitled "The longest pesach"](http://www.eichlers.com/shmuel-kunda-cd-the-longest-pesach.html) about a time when the Noda Beyehuda added on an extra day to Pesach in order to uncover a plot to poison the Jews of Prague. What is the source of this story?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Chaim Sheyaish Bahem - page 166](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48002&st=&pgnum=216) mentions this story. At the end of the story the [source mentioned](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48002&st=&pgnum=219) is  תולדות הנודע ביהודה page 138.

[Rabbi Amnon Yitzchak](https://www.shofar.tv/articles/7343) says this story in the name of the Avodas Hagershuni.

Comment: I was not able to find a copy of תולדות הנודע ביהודה anywhere, and the Avodas Hagershuni precedes the Noda B'Yehuda by many years